# How to add static value in tree view using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jstree

I am trying to use jstree (http://www.jstree.com/) in AngularJS. I made a simple example using jQuery [**Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/1/). I integrated that plugin to angular but it doesn't display my data. Why?

[**Preview**](http://plnkr.co/edit/G4lNlGGkredBDHC4lT3U?p=preview).

```
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-app="jsTreeApp">
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <jstree data="fff"></jstree>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Can we add static data in tree view as I did in fiddle?

Comment: Can you give us an example of your data?

Comment: you can ttake any simple data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Here's a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/qgjaw154/3/)

I have used your Plunker to create a jstree using AngularJS. Your code `var app = angular.module('jsTreeApp', ['jstree']);` will result to an error since the `jstree` plugin is not an Angular module. So I removed it.

You are correct that you need to use a directive to render the tree. I also modified your data in order for it to render correctly. See example data:

```
$scope.treeData = {
    "data": [{
        "text": "Basics",
        "state": "open",
        "children": [
        {
            "text": "login",
            "state": "closed",
            "children": [
                "login", 
                {
                    "text": "results",
                    "state": "open"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "text": "Basics",
            "state": "closed",
            "children": [
                "login",
                "something", 
                {
                    "text": "results",
                    "state": "closed"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }, {
        "text": "All",
        "state": "closed",
        "children": [{
            "text": "AddCustomer",
             "state": "closed",
             "children": [
                "login", 
                "Add",
                {
                    "text": "results",
                    "state": "closed"
                }
            ]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: can we drag and drop in that jstree

Comment: can you please tell me how we can start drag and drop

Comment: There is. They have an option for DND :)

Comment: can you please give fiddle while give drag and drop